# Getting Back in the Game[Android]

Tags: android

I am just getting back into Android programming, and need some help with one of my old projects. Can you tell me what's wrong with this code, or if it's just my computer derping out. It force closes no matter what. More files will be provided if needed.

```
package org.example.knitcalc;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Calc1 extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.Calc1);

        final TextView textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview); 
        final EditText op1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Int1);
        final EditText op2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Int2);
        final Button btnAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addBox);

        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int a, b;
        a = Integer.parseInt(op1.getText().toString());
        b = Integer.parseInt(op2.getText().toString());
        int sum = a + b;
        textview.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
        }
    });
    }
}
```

[EDIT]Here's the .xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@color/pcalc_back"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/Int1"
    android:width="110px" 
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:inputType="phone" />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/Int2"
    android:width="110px" 
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:inputType="phone" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/addBox"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/add_label" />
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="79dp"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Check whether textview, op1,op2,btnAdd returns null after findViewById line

Comment: Please provide your calc1 layout xml also..

Comment: Does it close immediately, or when you press the button?

Comment: @Geobits, it force closes as soon as it opens, with no user input.

Comment: Then assuming it is crashing in `onCreate` instead of anything after that(like `onResume`), it's got to be either that `Calc1` is capitalized like answered below, or `btnAdd` is null, like said above. Either way, a stack trace would most likely immediately pinpoint it.

Answer (score 3):

Try to rename res/layout/Calc1.xml to res/layout/calc1.xml and change

```
setContentView(R.layout.Calc1);
```

to

```
setContentView(R.layout.calc1);
```

Comment: good point.. layout names should never include capital letters I think

Answer (score 0):

Tigger is wrong I think. You defined the `OnClickListener` in a way that it is not necessary to implement the interface in your Activity.

Depending on the stacktrace (it will tell you why it crashes) it can be one of two things I think:

`R.id.Int1` or `R.id.Int2` should not start with a capital. Check if your references are right.

or

`Integer.parseInt(op1.getText().toString())` cannot parse that Value to an int value.

Comment: Okay. This part is fixed, but I need help with something else. Okay, so this is a part of  a calculator project.Calc1 and Calc2 are activities accessed through my KnitCalc activity. KnitCalc runs fine, but whenever I try to move into one of the calculator activities, the app force closes. Can anybody explain why this might be? I will put the .java and .xml files up in the main post if desired. Thank you all.

Comment: Was your original question answered? Then please make this another question and accept one of the answers on this page please.
We definitely need the stacktrace to answer it at least.